# How to invoke constructor of inner class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create an object of inner class using reflection. This is my class:

```
//outer class
public final class EMSToCompMessages {
private EMSToCompMessages() {}
//inner class
public static final class CompTypeConfig extends
{
    private CompTypeConfig(com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder<?> builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.unknownFields = builder.getUnknownFields();
    }
    private CompTypeConfig(boolean noInit) { 
        this.unknownFields = com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.getDefaultInstance(); 
    }

    private static final CompTypeConfig defaultInstance;
    public static CompTypeConfig getDefaultInstance() {
        return defaultInstance;
    }
}
```

I have to invoke inner class `CompTypeConfig` using reflection.
I am getting following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

What am I doing wrong?
I am using following code:

```
Class<?> loadedMyClass = Class.forName("EMSToCompMessages", true, loader);
        Constructor constructor = loadedMyClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Object obj = constructor.newInstance();
        Class[] innerClass = loadedMyClass.getDeclaredClasses();
        for (Class<?> getClass : innerClass) {
             Constructor ctor = getClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
                System.out.println(ctor.getName());
                ctor.setAccessible(true);
                Object innerObj = ctor.newInstance(obj);// Exception is coming here
        }
```

Comment: It's not an inner class, it's a static nested class. And if you want to construct it, you have to pass a parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You try to create a object of `CompTypeConfig` type which has no a constructor without parameters. `CompTypeConfig` has two constructors with `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder<?> builder` and `boolean noInit` params. You have to pass some param for them, when create object. Also as I understood, you pass incorrect parameter type for constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently trying to call

```
Object innerObj = constructor.newInstance(obj); //you wrote constru, which isn't defined
```

constructor.newInstance(obj) will try to create an instance of EMSToCompMessages class, not an inner class.

Anyway, the Javadoc says (about the **getConstructor** method)

> Returns a Constructor object that reflects the specified public
>   constructor of the class represented by this Class object. The
>   parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify
>   the constructor's formal parameter types, in declared order. If this
>   Class object represents an inner class declared in a non-static
>   context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing
>   instance as the first parameter.

So, you will first have to make your inner class constructors public. Calling setAccessible(true) is not enough in this case.